# Сортировка Google таблицы по столбцу Python

Tags: python

Задача состоит в том, чтобы выгрузить таблицу из Гугл Таблиц и сортировать ее по столбцу С.
[image: Таблица стран]

Получить данные я смог, но проблема заключается в том, что программа сортирует не по значению ячейки, а по первым символам в ячейке, таким образом на первом месте находится Канада с числом 9984670, затем Китай с числом 9598962 и т.д.
Каким образом можно исправить программу, чтобы она сортировала по значению?
Так же я выяснил, что выходные данные таблицы имеют тип list, а не, к примеру, словаря, как можно пофиксить и это?

```
def get_values(spreadsheet_id, range_name):
    ...
    try:
        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
        result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name).execute()
        return result
    ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = get_values(spreadsheetid, DefaultRange).get('values', {})
    sorted_a = sorted(a, key = lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
    print(sorted_a)
```

Comment: Ну попробуйте `key = lambda x: int(x[2])`, если я правильно понял вопрос

Comment: @CrazyElf, xD СПАСИБО! Я два дня не понимал, в чем проблема, но не ясно только что именно внутри программы происходило, она считала. что те числа имеют тип str? и поэтому сортировала их как слова?

Comment: Видимо да. Сортировка строк идёт посимвольным сравнением, а для правильной сортировки чисел нужно их в целом рассматривать. Это известная штука, часто встречается )

Comment: очень нужен твой код в качестве примера. Можешь дать ссылку на репозиторий с ним?